# Why docker switch to Linux containes error on Windows10 pc?

Tags: windows, docker

I want  to  use  docker  on win 10. But I can not  use images  by  "pull " because  My  engine  is  Windows . so I want to change to Linux . but something wrong with me .  (I can use docker before switch to Linux containers)
maybe my `hyper-v` is not normal. but how to fix it .

### There is my error info:

> Unable to create: The command that stopped the run because the
>   preference variable "ErrorActionPreference" or the generic parameter
>   is set to Stop: Since an object was not found, Hyper-V tried to access
>   the object on the computer "DESKTOP-ILCQ0I2" To the wrong. Verify that
>   the virtual machine management service on this computer is running. In
>   New-Switch, : Line 121 In , : line 411
>      In the Docker.Core.Pipe.NamedPipeClient.Send(String action,
>   Object[] parameters) location
>   C:\workspaces\stable-18.09.x\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Core\pipe
>   \NamedPipeClient.cs: line number 36    In the
>   Docker.Actions.<>c__DisplayClass28_0.b__0() location
>   C:\workspaces\stable-18.09.x\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Windows\Actions.cs: OK No. 305    In the
>   Docker.WPF.TaskQueue.<>c__DisplayClass19_0.<.ctor>b__1() location
>   C:\workspaces\stable-18.09.x\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.WPF\TaskQueue.
>   Cs: line number 59

Answer (score 0):

try the following commands:

```
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Hyper-V -All
```

reboot then:

```
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Containers -All
```

if that does't work see [this](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/1221#issuecomment-506538972)